# Nuxt3 with Nuxt-auth v5 works?

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, nuxt-auth

Can I use Nuxt-auth v5 (https://auth.nuxtjs.org/) with Nuxt3 (https://v3.nuxtjs.org/) and Vue3 ?

I'm trying to use `this.$auth.loginWith()` function of Nuxt-auth but i get an error like `this.$auth is undefined`. Also, nuxt config files are written in typescript as I'm working with nuxt3.

Does someone ever try to use these versions together ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

No. Unfortunately, @nuxtjs/auth v5 doesn't currently support Nuxt 3.

Maintainers are discussing of compatibility of the next version (v6).

You can read more in the thread: https://github.com/nuxt-community/auth-module/issues/1520

There is an alternative module, tho quite unstable: https://github.com/Teranode/nuxt-module-alternatives